# BigVideo.js |End video on the last frame

Tags: html, video

I'm using BigVideo.js to play a video in the background of a landing page, and I'm trying to get it to end on the last frame, how do I set the poster image to be the video's last frame? Would this be a setting to change in bigvideo.js or video.js?

Answer (score 0):

BigVideo.JS is based on Video.JS, so you can use Video.JS player API to accomplish that.

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
BV.init();
BV.show('some_video.mp4', {ambient:true}); // change the options as you like

// Pause at the end
BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () {
    this.pause();
});
```